# Why both string are not matching in the below script?

Tags: perl

i am giving the $second variable as:  `E:\oracle\V44\EBSapps\appl\admin\adalldefaults.txt<br/>`

both strings are same, but through that operator these are not matching. why?

```
my $first="E:\\oracle\\V44\\EBSapps\\appl\\admin\\adalldefaults.txt";
chomp(my $second=<STDIN>);

print "$first\n";
print "$second\n";
print length($first);print "\n";
print length($second);print "\n";

if ($first !~ /$second/i)
{
    print "string didn't matched\n";
}
else
{
    print "string matched\n";
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're matching in a Regexp context? so "\a" is interpreted as "a" or it has a special other meaning ? (wild guess, I didn't test). Therefore "\a" doesn't match "\a" anymore, but matches "a" or another thing if it's a special perl regexp char. (Same thing for "\o" and "\V" and "\E")

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$first !~ /\Q$second\E/i
```

The `\Q` will apply the `quotemeta` function which quotes all the special characters up to `\E`.